# Can Banelings overkill?

Tags: starcraft-2

Do Banelings actually overkill in certain situations or will they always deal only the required damage?

Usually 2 Banelings kill 1 Marine. Can I somehow force 3 or more Banelings to detonate on 1 Marine, without "shooting them down".

Comment: This call for science! But I am at work :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To test this I tried some of the following things a couple of times, always ended in same result, **no overkill**.

- Droped Marine has 45 hp and is Light unit so Banelings(with speed upgrade) do 35 damage.
- 2 Banelings needed to kill the Marine.
- 2 Banelings lost, no overkill.

- Walking Marine has 45 hp and is Light unit so Banelings(with speed upgrade) do 35 damage.
- 2 Banelings needed to kill the Marine.
- 2 Banelings lost, no overkill.

- Marine has 45 hp and is Light unit so Banelings(with speed upgrade and 3 weapon) do 47 damage.
- 1 Banelings needed to kill the Marine.
- 1 Banelings lost, no overkill.

- Marauder has 125 hp and is armored so Banelings(with speed upgrade)
  do 20 damage.
- 7 Banelings needed to kill the Marauder.
- 7 Banelings lost, no overkill.

Comment: There was no overkill from the banelings but there certainly was some in creating this answer.

Comment: Very well put together! Great taking the time to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You can press the "Explode" key (Default: X) to explode as many banelings as you want, even if there is no - or only one - enemy unit around.

The baneling explosion is a normal auto attack like the zerglings melee attack so they will only use it when they can actually hit a unit.

Comment: Yeah, but what would happen if drop a Marine into a bunch of Banelings? Would only 2 detonate?

Comment: @ayckoster yes. They auto-attack, 2 explode. The others don't find anything to auto-attack since the marine is already dead so they idle until they find more targets.

Answer (score 2):

NO, it's impossible.
I've tried a million creative ideas:

I tried just the normal way.
I tried dropping the marine.
I tried reducing the marine's HP to half and THEN attack with banelings.
I tried making a vortex with a mothership that would eat the 3 banelings and the marine but when they came out only 2 exploded.

The outcome of my research:

Can banelings overkill? no they can not.